# Tensorflow.js tf.loadModel() from localStorage not working

Tags: tensorflow.js

I am having problems using **tf.loadModel()**. I have built and trained a model and now I want to store it to the localStorage of my browser and retrieve it again.

```
path = 'localstorage://my-model'
const saveResults = model.saveModel(path)
var loadedModel;
tf.loadModel(path).then((data) => {loadedModel = data})
```

**loadedModel** is now i Tensorflow model object. But it is now identical to a newly created tf.sequential(). Below are the properties of **loadedModel** as presented by console.log(loadedModel). What could be the problem? I am fairly new at Promises, so the problem might lay there, however I have been experimenting with this for quite some time without making any progress.

I have checked **tf.io.listModels()** to check that the model indeed has been saved and that the file is not corrupted.

```
_addedWeightNames: Array []  
_built: false. 
_callHook: null. 
_losses: Array []. 
_nonTrainableWeights: Array []. 
_stateful: false. 
_trainableWeights:  Array []
_updatable: true
_updates: Array []
activityRegularizer: null
containerNodes: Set []
feedInputNames: Array []
feedInputShapes: Array []
feedOutputNames: Array []
id: 33
inboundNodes: Array [ {…}, {…} ]
initialWeights: null
inputLayers: Array []
inputLayersNodeIndices: Array []
inputLayersTensorIndices: Array []
inputNames: Array []
inputSpec: null
inputs: Array [ {…} ]
internalInputShapes: Array []
internalOutputShapes: Array []
layers: Array(6) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
layersByDepth: Object {  }
name: "sequential_5"
nodesByDepth: Object {  }
outboundNodes: Array []
outputLayers: Array []
outputLayersNodeIndices: Array []
outputLayersTensorIndices: Array []    
outputNames: Array []
outputs: Array [ {…} ]
supportsMasking: false
trainable: true
```

While console.log(model) shows this:

```
_addedWeightNames: Array []
_built: true
_callHook: null
_losses: Array []
_nonTrainableWeights: Array []
_stateful: false
_trainableWeights: Array []
_updatable: true
_updates: Array []
activityRegularizer: null
containerNodes: Set(7) [ "dense_Dense1_ib-0", "flatten_Flatten1_ib-0",     "max_pooling2d_MaxPooling2D2_ib-0", … ]
feedInputNames: Array []
feedInputShapes: Array []
feedOutputNames: Array []
id: 0
inboundNodes: Array [ {…}, {…} ]
initialWeights: null
inputLayers: Array [ {…} ]
inputLayersNodeIndices: Array [ 0 ]
inputLayersTensorIndices: Array [ 0 ]
inputNames: Array [ "conv2d_Conv2D1_input" ]
inputSpec: null
inputs: Array [ {…} ]
internalInputShapes: Array []
internalOutputShapes: Array []
layers: Array(6) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
layersByDepth: Object {  }
loss: "categoricalCrossentropy"
metrics: Array [ "accuracy" ]
metricsNames: Array [ "loss", "acc" ]
metricsTensors: Array [ (2) […] ]
model: Object { _stateful: false, id: 8, supportsMasking: false, … }
name: "sequential_1"
nodesByDepth: Object(7) [ (1) […], (1) […], (1) […], … ]
optimizer: Object { learningRate: 0.15, c: {…} }
outboundNodes: Array []
outputLayers: Array [ {…} ]
outputLayersNodeIndices: Array [ 0 ]
outputLayersTensorIndices: Array [ 0 ]
outputNames: Array [ "dense_Dense1" ]
​outputs: Array [ {…} ]
supportsMasking: false
trainable: true
```

Comment: What does console.log model show? So what changed between saving?

Comment: @SebastianSpeitel Now I have added the output for console.log(model). As you can see, quite different. So there is something wrong with how I load the model. Could it be related to how I use the promises or something about the localStorage? It all seems strange to me.

Comment: You are logging the loaded model after the promise has resolved? (In . then()?)

Comment: No, you are right. But I am debugging in the console of my webbrowser. So later, after the promise has been resolved, I just write "loadedModel" in the console to produce that output!